# Customization of wpf expander

Tags: wpf, customization, expander

I am new to WPF. I want to create a menu like given in the picture in wpf. i have created menu,but don't know how to create extendable menu items

[image: 1]

also i want  the arrow in shape as underline in picture.

Answer (score 0):

This should get your started.

```
        <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Width="200" Background="#394768" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Verdana">
            <Expander.Header>
                <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Schedule" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="calendar.png" Width="20" Height="20" />
                </Grid>
            </Expander.Header>
            <Menu Background="#232230" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Verdana">
                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <MenuItem Header="Department Schedule" />
                <MenuItem Header="Employee Schedule"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Temporary Schedule"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Schedule View"/>
            </Menu>
        </Expander>
```

Here's the calendar.png that I used for this example (*WARNING: IT'S WHITE SO YOU WILL NEED TO CLICK ON IT TO SEE IT*):

[image]

Now if you want to change the arrow icon to something that looks like the picture you provided, you will need to override the Expander's ControlTemplate entirely, and replace it with your own arrow icon. [Here's a good guide from codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248112/Templating-WPF-Expander-Control). It will take some studying and understanding on your part here, so I will leave that exercise up to you.